# Unix shell - How to have a prompt that change randomly

Tags: shell, unix, random, zsh, prompt

I was wondering if there is any way to have a prompt that change every time i press Enter, like:

```
[jtouzea - such prompt]  $>
[jtouzea - much style]   $> ls -l
total 0
drwx------+  5 jtouzea  2013  170 Mar 11 16:50 Desktop
drwx------+  2 jtouzea  2013   68 Mar 11 16:49 Documents
drwx------+  2 jtouzea  2013   68 Mar 11 16:58 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x@ 26 jtouzea  2013  884 Mar 11 17:20 Library
drwx------+  2 jtouzea  2013   68 Mar 11 16:50 Movies
drwx------+  2 jtouzea  2013   68 Mar 11 16:50 Music
drwx------+  2 jtouzea  2013   68 Mar 11 16:50 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x+  2 jtouzea  2013   68 Mar 11 16:50 Public
[jtouzea - wow]          $> echo "test"
test
[jtouzea - 10/10]        $>
```

i have already found the $RANDOM command, that allow to do so, but i need to do:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

or else i doesn't change my prompt.

Any idea?

EDIT:
Currently i have:

```
PROMPT="[jtouzea - $RANDOM] $> "
```

in my .zshrc

EDIT2:
I use zsh, so unfortunately, PROMPT_COMMAND doesn't seems to work

EDIT3:
Here is my final code now that the question is solved:

```
function precmd()
{
    sentence[1]="much prompt";
    sentence[2]="such style";
    sentence[3]="wow";
    nb=$[$RANDOM % 3 + 1];
    PROMPT="[jtouzea - ${sentence[$nb]}] $> ";
}
```

Comment: Could you upload your `.zshrc` file contents, or at least the relevant code excerpt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `PROMPT_COMMAND` hook:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND() { randPromptNum=$[ $RANDOM % 3 ]; PS1=${POSSIBLE_PROMPTS[$randPromptNum]};}
```

For zsh, you must use `precmd` instead of `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Before you use this, you must set up a variable with all possible prompts:

```
POSSIBLE_PROMPTS[0]="such prompt: "
POSSIBLE_PROMPTS[1]="much style: "
POSSIBLE_PROMPTS[2]="wow: "
```

If you want to adjust the number of prompts possible, remember to edit the `% 3`.

**EDIT** - Result on cygwin

```
much style: echo hi
hi
such prompt: echo blah
blah
much style: pwd
/usr/bin
such prompt: yes y | head
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
wow: echo foo
foo
such prompt:
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work in zsh, but it work in bash... any hook for zsh?

Comment: For zsh change `PROMPT_COMMAND` to `precmd`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same shell as yours, but you could try this:

I edited my .kshrc file like this:

```
PS1="Look, it's random: \$RANDOM  \$ "
```

And then sourced the file, and pressed Enter several times:

```
/home/user  $ . .kshrc
Look, it's random: 2155  $
Look, it's random: 6032  $
Look, it's random: 13065  $
```

Put all your phrases in a text file or an array and then use $RANDOM to look into that.

Note: remember to escape the `$`.

Comment: PROMPT="Look, it's random: \$RANDOM  \$ " does: "Look, it's random: $RANDOM" and without escape $, it does "Look, it's random: 21349  $" everytime

Comment: @BusyBeingDelicious hm, should be something to do with zsh...  I got a different number each time a new line gets printed - that is, each time I press the Enter key.  My test was done using ksh.